# The requested resource is not available Spring 3 MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting the requested resource () is not available displayed in the browser and I can not understand what I am doing wrong.

This is my applicationContext-dispatcher.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp"/>

</beans>
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-main.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-hibernate.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-jms.xml
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext-i18n.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext-dispatcher.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

This is the redirect.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% response.sendRedirect("index.htm"); %>
```

And the index.jsp page is located under the WEB-INF/jsp.

When open the browser I see the 404 error code generated from tomcat ant the message that resource is not available. I don't understand what is wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, have you defined any controller mapping for index.htm? Spring won't "automatically" forward the request to your index.jsp view, you need to define a controller to handle the index.htm url.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/index.htm")
    public String handleIndexGet() {
        return "index"; // forward to view index.jsp
    }

}
```

Comment: You are right. I have defined the controller and now it works, thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Resources which are inside the **WEB-INF** folder aren't accessible to the outside world (JSP file in your case). Means that you can not simply hit the URL and see the JSP file.

For example, you have the following JSP,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

then you can not simply hit the browser using:

```
http://localhost:8080/project-name/WEb-INF/nameofpage.jsp
```

It will throw the same error. Though you can programmatically access those resources inside WEB-INF folder.

Write the following controller:

```
package your.apckage.name;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sample() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And add the following line in spring -config file:

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="package name of the controller" />
```

Comment: Yes, I know that. But when entering for e.g: http://localhost/myAppContextPath/index.htm it also generates me resource not found. I have declared the dispatcher servlet and view resolver bean in dispatcher spring context so I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: it should be localhost:portno/myAppContextPath/redirect.jsp. Not the index.htm. since you have specified your welcome-file as redirect.jsp

Comment: My server port is 80, so there is no need to specify it.

Comment: okey, you may not need to specify it but you have to write redirect.jsp instead of index.htm

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be

```
<% response.sendRedirect("index.jsp"); %>
```

Also, since you're doing a redirect, the `index.jsp` has to be present outside WEB-INF to be accessible to your browser.

Comment: No it shouldn't. He has already defined **<url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>** So the requested page must end with .htm, otherwise the **dispatcherServlet** won't be called.

Comment: Oh, yes. I didn't notice that.

Comment: its customary in stackoveflow to upvote a comment if you find it useful.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi done =) But the tooltip for the comment upvote button actually says "This is a great comment" ;)

Comment: hahaha, then we should request stackoverflow to change the tooltip. :P

Answer (score 0):

Generally **requested resource not found** error comes when there is a problem in URL mapping. When the requested URL does not match to any of the URL patterns, it throws this exception.

Comment: But it matches the url-pattern *.htm. It is declared in web.xml